# Scroll dentro de DIV jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy creando un chatbot con jquery. Quiero que al momento de mostrar los mensajes del chat, la ventana se enfoque o haga scroll al ultimo mensaje.

La ventana de chat bot html

```
<div class="chatter"  id="div-to-toggle"  style="display: none;">

  <div class="card chatter_convo text-dark bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="container sticky-top chat-header ">
        <span>ChatBot</span>
        <a href="#"><i id="close-btn" class="far fa-2x fa-times-circle" style="font-size: 32px !important; color:#162a67;   position: relative; float: right; transform: translateY(-5px);"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
        <div class="chatList">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <span class="chatter_msg_item chatter_msg_item_admin" style="display:none" id="bienvenida">
        <a href="https://lukepeters.tech" class="chatter_avatar"><img src="https://img.lukepeters.me/avatar.jpg" /></a>
        <strong class="chatter_name">Robot</strong>Hola, soy un chatbot y estoy para ayudarte respondiendo tus dudas!</span>

        <span class="chatter_msg_item chatter_msg_item_admin" style="display:none" id="bienvenida2">
        <a href="https://lukepeters.tech" class="chatter_avatar"><img src="https://img.lukepeters.me/avatar.jpg" /></a>
        <strong class="chatter_name">Robot</strong>¿En que estás interesado? <br>
        <button type="button" id="bot1ask1" class="btn-secundary botones-chat">Tuberías</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-secundary botones-chat">Mangueras</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-secundary botones-chat">Otros</button>       
        </span>
```

El fragmento de html que he utilizado para probar el scroll es el siguiente span

```
<span class="chatter_msg_item chatter_msg_item_user" id="user1ask1" style="display:none">
            <a href="https://lukepeters.tech" class="chatter_avatar"><img src="http://img.lukepeters.me/jack.jpg" /></a>
            <strong class="chatter_name">Tú</strong>Quiero conocer mas sobre tuberías</span>
     
       </div>
    </div>
```

Y por otra parte dejo el fragmento del

```
$( "#bot1ask1" ).click(function() {
  $("#user1ask1").show();
```

Entre tantas cosas, una de ellas fue que intenté usar la [API ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

```
    $('#user1ask1').scrollTo(100);
```

pero sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar. Agradezco cualquier aporte

tambien intenté esto y sigue sin funcionar

```
$('.chatter .card'). scrollTop( $('.chatter .card')[0]. scrollHeight );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado colocándolo dentro del mensaje especifico y usando una clase distinta a card .

```
$( "#bot1ask1" ).click( function() {
        $("#user1ask1").show();
        $('.chatter .chatter_convo').scrollTop($('.chatter .chatter_convo')[0].scrollHeight );

});
```